# Returning from Dual-boot to just Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, multi-boot

I installed Ubuntu sometime back along side Vista, but later found that I rarely (if ever) use Ubuntu. How easy is it to return my computer to its initial state of having only one OS, and freeing up the hard-drive space used by the Ubuntu install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two factors here:

- first, repair the MBR so that you can boot to Windows (it may be dangerous to start deleting partitions if you aren't sure that your boot-loader doesn't use them). This [knowledge-base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919529) covers some scenarios, but make sure you understand it before hacking around...
- second, use disk management in Windows to identify and remove the offending partitions

Be cautious. Most of these operations can (if done incorrectly) leave your system unbootable, and/or cause data loss. Perhaps backup any critical data first.

Comment: @Marc: I would change 'Perhaps' to definitely.

Comment: is there no step by step instruction set to post here instead of linking to somewhere else?